# Better way to convert NSArray of NSString to NSArray of NSNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsnumber

Is there is a better way to convert `NSArray` of `NSString` into `NSArray` of `NSNumber` than the following code:

```
-(NSArray*) convertStringArrayToNumberArray:(NSArray *)strings {
    NSMutableArray *numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:strings.count];
    for (NSString *string in strings) {
        [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[string integerValue]]];
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so; that looks like good code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
-(NSArray *)convertStringArrayToNumberArray:(NSArray *)strings {
    return [strings valueForKeyPath:@"self.integerValue"];
}
```

I test

```
NSArray * array = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];
NSArray *num = [self convertStringArrayToNumberArray:array];
```

And result

[image]